# Sort second to fifth column for each row in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in **R**, and I need to sort each row for the second to fifth column independently.

For example, I have the following

```
1 2 3 1 4 5
2 1 3 2 6 7
3 7 2 1 3 2
...
```

and I need to get

```
1 1 2 3 4 5
2 1 2 3 6 7
3 1 2 2 3 7
...
```

How to do this quickly and beautifully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may be useful

```
> cbind(df[,1], t(apply(df[,-1], 1, sort)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    2    1    2    3    6    7
[3,]    3    1    2    2    3    7
```

where `df` is a data.frame:

```
df <- read.table(text="1 2 3 1 4 5
2 1 3 2 6 7
3 7 2 1 3 2", header=FALSE)
```

Comment: Also, without the use of `cbind`, `df[-1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, sort))`